# "http://192.168.0.137:8080" link is not working

Tags: angular

I created an html file, js file and tsv file in sublime. Next I moved to the project folder  and started the server by typing http-server, it generated "http://192.168.0.137:8080", "http://127.0.0.1:8080", when I'm trying to execute the link in the browser it is showing the following error:

> "This page isn’t working192.168.0.137 sent an invalid response.
>   ERR_INVALID_REDIRECT"

Comment: like the error says, it's an invalid redirect. what exactly is your configuration? where is it trying to redirect you?  have you checked your network calls?

Comment: Maybe try using `https` instead of `http`.

Comment: tried,but same error

Comment: how to check network calls

Comment: can i get the response please...

Comment: Check the web developer tools in your browser, on Windows with F12. Check there the network tab.

Answer (score 0):

`http-server` will create a local-server, where your files will be hosted.
For your case, you are trying to host an `Angular` project.

Follow these steps:

1. run `ng build` in the angular project, which will generate a `dist`
   folder.
2. Go inside `dist/YOUR_PROJECT_DIRECTORY/`
3. open `cmd` and run `http-server -p8080`
4. go to  `http://localhost:8080`